# How to debug in Tryton?

Tags: debugging, tryton

I'm trying to found a more detailed and focused way to get error message from views in Tryton Client for speed development.  I'm using 
`tryton -v -d -l DEBUG` 
but only bring UNICODE strings arriving to client. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I usually work with eclipse and pydev plugin. The installation is the same as OpenERP [1].

[1] http://domatix.com/entorno-desarrollo-eclipse-openerp-parte-tres/

Comment: To debbug using Pycharm here is a guide http://blog.geniali.ch/post/2011/10/31/Tryton-Teil-5-Installation-und-Konfiguration-PyCharm.aspx/en

Answer (score 0):

Just like the client, the server can be run in verbose mode where stack traces are sent out to stderr and stdout. But this stack trace is no different from the unicode stack trace displayed by the tryton client. So the better way to debug once you find such an error would be to set a breakpoint around the code where the stacktrace frame indicates the exception occurred.

See: https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/ for a quick guide on pdb if you are using pdb for the first time.

OTOH, if you want to capture more information in production when exceptions occur, use the trytond-sentry integration module(See: http://www.openlabs.co.in/article/sentry-tryton-v-1-0)